Running Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS from a KVM causes long running processes to freeze/close when switching devices
I'm Running Ubuntu 20.04.6 from a KVM and when I switch to a different computer, long running processes will either close or hang. For example, CMake will hang in the middle of a build or Steam will close.
I have a NVidia GTX4070 and running nvidia-driver-535
How can I fix this?
